# Materializecss 2.0.1 : problem with Label in Selects

Tags: javascript, materialize

Im using Materializecss 2.0.1 and the  in the select dissapear.
My code:
`<select required class="validate" name="id_provincia" id="id_provincia"> <option value="" disabled selected>Sel. una opción</option> <?php foreach ($data[list_provincias] as $k=>$prov){ ?> <option <?php if($prov[id]==$data['record']['id_provincia']){ echo "selected='selected' "; }elseif($prov[id]=='22' && !$data['record']['id_provincia']){ echo "selected='selected'";  } ?> value="<?php echo $prov[id]; ?>"><?php echo $prov[provincia]; ?></option> <?php } ?> </select> <label for="id_provincia">Provincia</label> <span class="helper-text">Sel. Provincia</span>`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fuKu.png)

Im try copy and pastle the example, erease all includes (except materializecss) and still the bug.
["Materialize Select" is the label. This is a example in the official doc - https://materializeweb.com/select.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08D1S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, im find the bug.

If you initialize a  and initialize again  the label tag dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you wrap it in a .input-field for proper alignment with other text fields. and add a condition for first option if $data['record']['id_provincia'] == null should be selected else the first options should not be selected

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled <?php if($data['record']['id_provincia'] == null) { ?> selected <?php } ?> >Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>
```

Initialization

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems,{});
  });
    
  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
</script>
```

[image]

the Full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@2.0.1-alpha/dist/css/materialize.min.css
" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>
  </div>

<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@2.0.1-alpha/dist/js/materialize.min.js
"></script>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
      var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems,{});
    });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ty for the answered.... this not is the problem. The problem: "<label>Materialize Select</label>" not display (see img)

Comment: @bacc i update anser try to initialize the select just like this and if not work you have to check in chrome console if other library make conflit with Materializecss